# Call xbacklight through API

Tags: python, c++, c, xorg, backlight

Does there exist an API for the `xbacklight` utility?

I'd like to make a graphical frontend in either C, C++, or Python, but I can't find any documentation.

My only guess at integration at this point would be making a call to `system()`, but I like to call libraries directly.

Does `xbacklight` have a library interface, or do I have to just call the executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xbacklight source code can be found [here](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xbacklight/).

It wouldn't be hard to modify the C source into an API for other languages.